# iptables:How to configure PREROUTE rule allowing port redirection from deducated IP addresses?

Tags: iptables

I have the following rule in my iptables that redirects port 5060 to 5065.

**-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5065**

I 'd like to apply this rule for several external IPs only, e.g. for example, to **123.123.123.123** and **124.124.124.124** only.

I added the following rule instead of above:

**-A PREROUTING -s 123.123.123.123 -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5065**

But then when I tried to add the next rule:

**-A PREROUTING -s 124.124.124.124 -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5065**

I got the following message:

**iptables: No chain/target/match by that name**

How to put these rules properly?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

For preprouting and postrouting you have t specify that you are working on the NAT chain.

ie : 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 124.124.124.124 -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 5065